# How to create Android-M Preview emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-6.0-marshmallow

I think I have installed all the system images required for android m preview, but still my emulator is showing nothing, its always blank. Please help me

[image]
[image]

After Suggestion i have downloaded the other requirements, but still its not working

[image]

Comment: Did you try deactivating the checkbox "Use Host GPU" within the settings of the virtual device?

Comment: @Doraemon created a demo for permissions in android-m where I have listed the things which we need to install for android-m.Also have created Android M emulator to test my code. https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/Android-M-RuntimePermissionDemo :-)

Comment: @jorge it didnt work :(

Comment: @nitesh, thanks but still it didn't work

Comment: @Doraemon look this link about how to set up Android Emulator for Android M http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-get-android-m-preview-windows-mac-installing-sdk-1503593

Comment: @jorge : Thanks, i m looking into it

Comment: Showing empty for my Macbook as well, launching Lollipop images has no issues!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have sufficient files to create the emulator might be you are editing the existing emulator, i suggest try to create a new emulator, and try to keep the Ram consumption lower to get better performance.

Refer from the above link you can create your new emulator by following below steps
Step-1: Go to Android SDK folder and run AVD Manager. Click on Create

Note: Use default value for Max VM application heap. As Android supports variety of displays, you can explore with different devices by selecting in Device: dropdown

Step-2: Select the virtual device which you just now created and click Start

Step-3: Do not make any change under Launch Options and click on Launch button

Step-4: Emulator will start a few Command Prompt windows flicker. You should now see the following screen, with the Android device booting up, which will take about five minutes

Step-5: You should now see a screen saying Emulator has been successfully installed

Your Windows/Mac PC should now be ready to get started with the Developer Preview.

Comment: Indeed your were correct!  the issue was on editing configuration of the existing nexus 5, and after creating a new one its working perfectly fine

Comment: After create new AVD, still shows blank screen for me :(

Comment: Are you following the same steps otherwise mention the steps you are following.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Android SDK manager you need to download the Android m preview section.Then follow these steps

Step 1:  Run AVD Manager and click on Create.

Note : Select a small resolution screen if your RAM is low.It will be a plus in case of performance part.

Step 2:Enter the Ram value to 1Gb if your system(Computer)RAM is about 4gb or RAM value as 2gb your system(Computer)RAM is about 6gb or 8gb.

Step 3:Select the device which you created now, press Start and select Launch Button.

Step 4:You should get a alert box showing that Successfully installed.

Step 5:An android device with android device booting up screen will be appeared and it will take time depending upon the RAM you allocated at the time of creating the Android Device in AVD.

**NOTE**make sure not to run too many another programs while you trying to launch or using the emulator.(make sure the IDE is uptodate)

Happy Android M Preview....

Comment: but i used these emulators with less ram. My system has 8 Gb ram, and i edited these emulators to consume only 512 Mb Ram, to avoid stumble execution of other programs. But my problem gets fixed when i create a new emulator, i think upgrading an existing emulator with M preview was the issue here. thanks for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create **MNC(Android M Preview)** emulators, you could follow these steps:

**1**, Of course, downloads **MNC System images**. Open **SDK Manager**, select images like **Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image**, **ARM 64 v8a System Image**, **ARM EABI v7a System Image** and something like that.

**2**, open **AVD Manager** by clicking the button on the top of Android Studio. Then you will see "**Your Virtual Devices**" window.

**3**, Click the button of "**Create Virtual Device**" at the left bottom of the window. Then you will see "**Select Hardware**" window.

**4**, then select the category and name of the emulator you want, and then "**Next**".

**5**, if you have succeeded downloading **MNC System Images**, you will see them from the "**API Level**"

**6**, and then click "**Next**", you will see "**Android Virtual Device(AVD)**" window, you can change settings if you want to.

**7**, click "**Finish**" and wait, util emulators are prepared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, 
I copied the system image from the default directory: 
C:\Users\eli\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\system-images\android-MNC\default\arm64-v8a

to the image root dir:
C:\Users\eli\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\system-images\android-MNC\arm64-v8a

I restarted eclise, and now, I could see the android M and the arm64 system image.